# Create a new account while sync outlook contacts to D365

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I want to create a new account record while syncing outlook contacts to D365.

Example: In outlook, I have a contact with following details.

( Name: Cathon Cook, Account: Alphen House, Mail:cook@gmail.com)

When I go and import this contact to D365 from outlook, the only contact is creating. That is fine but I want to create an account (with a name: Alphen House) If the Account/Organization with that contact does not exist in the account record.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a plugin - register it to run on the create of the contact record, check to see if the matching account exists, and create the account if it does not.

Comment: Thank you @Matt. Can't we implement with out of box functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Create a workflow against the contact entity.
You can then add a step to check if the contact's account field has a value then create an account record.